# simplify list `grep` facility in the code

Tags: groovy

I want to get all the `ClassNode` fields with a certain conditions. 
In my code it looks like this:

```
listener.classNode.fields.grep {
    !it.name.startsWith('$') &&
    !it.name.startsWith('_') &&
    !it.name.equals('metaClass') &&
    !it.name.startsWith('this')
}.collect{ it.name }
```

Is there a way to make it better? I mean get rid of those several conditional statements inside `grep` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a bit shorter with getting the `name` value a bit earlier:

```
listener.classNode.fields*.name.grep {
    !it.startsWith('$') &&
    !it.startsWith('_') &&
    !it.equals('metaClass') &&
    !it.startsWith('this')
}
```

When it comes to the condition itself, this may be shorter a bit:

```
assert ['$a', '_a', 'metaClass', 'this', 'FOUND'].grep { n ->  
    !['$', '_', 'this'].any { a -> n.startsWith(a) } &&
    !n.equals('metaClass')
} == ['FOUND']
```

Remember that the latter - even if it's more groovier - may be less readable by humans and these are humans who mainly work with code ;)

Comment: I am aiming for the fancy code  only I can understand, so human readability does not bother me.